# Assign a dynamically allocated array in a constructor to a unique smart pointer member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

In the example below, I have a smart pointer `sp` as a member variable and I want to assign a dynamically allocated array to it in the constructor, however I get a compiler error `no match for ‘operator=’`, what is the correct way to do this?

In the example below, I have a smart pointer `sp` as a member variable and I want to assign a dynamically allocated array to it in the constructor, is using the `reset()` method of smart pointer the correct way to do this or should I be using a shared smart pointer?

```
struct SampleStructure
{
std::unique_ptr<idx_t[]> sp;

SampleStructure(int a, int b){

    sp.reset(new idx_t[a + 1]); 
 }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `operator=` because [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) can't be [assigned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) from raw pointers directly, as you showed, you have to use [`reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset), which would replace the managed object (after the initialization of the `unique_ptr`).

You can initialize the data member `sp` via member initializer list in the constructor directly; then you don't need the "assignment" (replacement). e.g.

```
SampleStructure(int a, int b) : sp(std::make_unique<idx_t[]>(a + 1)) {}
```